# google map showing white tile

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

For some reason my map is showing a white tile. The tiles affected are where a marker is placed or where a poly line is draw (try entering a city/postcode).

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The style for the `canvas` tag was being overridden.